How can I determine if a column in a group of rows is homogeneous or heterogenous in Excel?
I have some data that looks like this, already grouped by GroupID:



ItemID
GroupID
Color




1
1
Yellow


2
1
Yellow


3
2
Blue


4
2
Blue


5
2
Blue


6
2
Blue


7
3
Yellow


8
3
Blue


9
3
Yellow


10
4
Blue


11
4
Red


12
4
Yellow


13
4
Red



I need to determine if the color value is the same on all members of each GroupId, and 'output' it in a new set of cells that signify the 'overall' color of each GroupID, like this:



GroupID
OverallColor




1
Yellow


2
Blue


3
Mixed


4
Mixed



In other words, if all values of Color are the same for a given groupID, I need that value. If the values of Color are not all the same (one or more is different from the others) I need the value "mixed".
This data is thousands of rows, so I can do whatever basic filtering and grouping would help facilitate a solution. If it helps, 'Yellow', 'Blue', and 'Red' are the only possible values in the data, so the solution doesn't have to allow for all possible color values.

I remember @JvdV giving a genius improvement to this answer
The insight was that the aggregation function in a Groupby doesn't have to be just sum, average etc., it can be any lambda function of your choice.
We can apply the same method to this situation:
=GROUPBY(B2:B14,C2:C14,LAMBDA(x,IF(ROWS(UNIQUE(x))=1,@x,"Mixed")),0,0)



Here's one way you can do it, it assumes the sample data is in A1:C14.
First get all the unique GroupIDs using this formula,
=UNIQUE(B1:B14)
which I put in F1.
Now in G2 enter this formula and copy it down.
=LET(colors, UNIQUE(FILTER($C$1:$C$14, $B$1:$B$14=F2)), IF(COUNTA(colors)=1, colors, "Mixed"))

